# sudo apt-get Conflicting values set for option

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install missing module packages in my Ubuntu installation. When trying to update Ubuntu for this, I am running into following error.

Command: `sudo apt update`

Error:

> Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source
> https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu/ focal:
> /usrshare/keyrings/nginx-keyring.gpg !=
> /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-keyring.gpg